# Is it possible to refer to project files in code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file-io

In Visual Studio (VB.NET), I want to open a file and read the contents into a string. It's easy enough when the file is in a known location on disk, since you can reference it as C:\Windows\foo.txt or whatever. Is there any way to refer to files based on their location in the solution? For example, MySolution\MyProject\MyFolder\foo.txt. The file to read will be a SQL file, so there won't be any code objects in it to work with.

I use a whole bunch of different solutions that are stored in various places on disk, so I really don't want to have to deal with the file system directly. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use application path!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the file properties for the file in the solution, you'll notice that one of the options is "Copy to Output Directory".  You need to set that to either "Copy always" or "Copy if newer".  Once you set that on all the pertinent files and re-build the project, you will notice that all of those files will be copied to the `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` folder (which ever one you were building to) as part of the build process.  Now, in your application, you can just assume that they will be in the same directory as your application.

Comment: Thanks! If this works, it's going to make writing SQL queries infinitely better.

Answer (score 1):

`Dim s as string = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` will return the executable's directory.
If you're always running this via the IDE, or from the build folder, this will be MySolution/MyProject/bin/(Debug or Release).
Then `System.IO.Directory.GetParent(s)` twice should get you the project folder path.

Comment: I was just about to ask this...too bad I can only mark one answer

Comment: That's one way to do it, but since the current directory can be changed, it's safer to use the assembly's path (e.g. `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`).